# A drupal site inside another drupal subdirectory

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, drupal-6, settings

I have been trying to install a drupal site inside another drupal site subdirectory. but I get page not found errors for the inner site.

Example I have **www.drupalsite.com** point to folder-------->**public/**
and I have another drupal installation **www.drupalsite.com/drupaltracker** point to folder------>**public/tracker/**

However, whenever I try to access page for drupaltracker eg www.drupalsite.com/drupaltracker/admin/ , I get a 404 error

I have tried changing baseurl in settings.php of www.drupalsite.com/drupaltracker/ but still I get 404 errors. Any kind soul can provide me the right direction.

Thanks a tonne in advance!

Comment: Why? One Drupal installation can contain multiple sites.

Comment: One Drupal installation can support multiple sites via the multisite installation (http://drupal.org/getting-started/6/install/multi-site) but one Drupal installation folder cannot contain another Drupal installation folder; thats what I have come to understand :P

Comment: I have exactly same requirement as yours. I want to run a Development server for developers to play around. My development server would be in http://example.com/Development whereas main server will be in http://example.com. I need the development server's database all separate so that it doesn't mess up with the original one. How do I do this? Can this be achieved using multi-site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a development server, why not create a new virtual host? It will save you some trouble. Drupal isn't really built to run recursively inside another Drupal. There's no point.

If you must do this, check the .htaccess of the parent drupal and make sure there are no collisions there.

:)

Comment: how can I check for collisions in htaccess? (On a side note, your missing socks site seems quite useful :P)

Comment: You'd have to take a look ye olde eyeball style. I am not fluent in rewrite rules and all that but it's the most likely problem. It's not going to be easy to debug it. Thanks for lookin at my socks site! Keep your eye out for some socks huh? :)

Answer (score 2):

original .htaccess have following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You need to modify root .htaccess, if you wish to have another copy of drupal in "mobile/" subdirectory. See my sample:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your purpose for wanting another drupal install inside of a drupal installation. But if you are referring to [multisite](http://drupal.org/getting-started/6/install/multi-site) you should click on that link. It provides a method to host multiple "sites" off of a common codebase.

Comment: No, I am not referring to multisite installation. Its just that I was experimenting on my development server which has a Drupal installation at the root and I do not wish to touch it. Also, I wanted to quickly test another Druapl site without having to change DNS. For a multisite installation all sites should be pointing to same codebase and I cannot change DNS as of now.